# Getting specific location's latitude and longitude data set saved in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, data-retrieval

In my Firebase Database, I set it like this:

[image: Current Firebase data]

The latitude and longitude are represented by `0` and `1` respectively. I am currently using hard-coded method to obtain the latitude, longitude and name:

```
Firebase locationRef = mRootRef.child("loc");
        locationRef.addValueEventListener(new com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                Double latitude = dataSnapshot.child("0").getValue(Double.class);
                Double longitude = dataSnapshot.child("1").getValue(Double.class);
                String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);}
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                throw firebaseError.toException();

            }
        });
```

Now I set my data as shown in the image:

[image: New Firebase data set]

How can I obtain the data value of variable (`0`, `1` and `name`) for loc1 and loc2 in a manner that I can obtain them easily without hard-coding. The number of locations will increase in number too in the future too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like folowing

Need to add getChildren() foreach it will give your all location under loc
you can take that info in some other array also

```
Firebase locationRef = mRootRef.child("loc");
locationRef.addValueEventListener(new com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


        for (DataSnapshot snapm: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

            Double latitude = snapm.child("0").getValue(Double.class);
            Double longitude = snapm.child("1").getValue(Double.class);
            String name = snapm.child("name").getValue(String.class);}
        }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
        throw firebaseError.toException();

    }
});
```